# PowerVR Android sample: makefile not working

Tags: android, android-ndk, cygwin, powervr-sgx

I'm having a hard time setting up PowerVR SDK for Android on Windows 8 64, assuming I met all requirements:

- Android SDK (fresh Eclipse)
- Android NDK
- Cygwin (with make)
- PowerVR Android SDK 3.0

I can perfectly make and run an Android NDK sample. However, the same process fails for building any PowerVR sample (from the SDK). Here's the output when I try to run the makefile:

> $ ndk
>   Compile++ thumb  : OGLES2Texturing <= OGLES2Texturing.cpp
>   arm-linux-androideabi-g++.exe: error: C:/cygwin///cygdrive/c/Users/stfn/workspaces/android/03_Texturing/jni/OGLES2Texturing.cpp: No such file or directory
>   arm-linux-androideabi-g++.exe: fatal error: no input files
>   compilation terminated.
>   /cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r8d/build/core/build-binary.mk:269: recipe for target `obj/local/armeabi/objs/OGLES2Texturing//cygdrive/c/Users/stfn/workspaces/android/03_Texturing/jni/OGLES2Texturing.o' failed
>   make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/OGLES2Texturing//cygdrive/c/Users/stfn/workspaces/android/03_Texturing/jni/OGLES2Texturing.o] Error 1

I suppose the error should be related to a wrong path given to the compiler. To me it looks like a mixture of standard Windows and Cygwin/Unix paths: *** C:/cygwin///cygdrive/c/Users/stfn/...***

If been through so many makefiles now trying to resolve this issue but I just don't know where else to look. This is the first time I tried messing with the NDK. I'm afraid this could be my last.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

1.in the Android.mk file, for the PVRSDKDIR, set the path of your project folder in your workspace.
2.Copy the build, tools, and shell folders from the powervr sdk folder to your project folder